Google Chrome is stuck on version 70.55.49213
What is the next logical step to completely uninstall a corrupted Google Chrome application?
I've tried uninstalling Google Chrome, remove registry entries via tools like Revo Uninstaller, deleting folders in Users\<my user>\Appdata and Program files(x86).
I've also tried uninstalling and installing via winget.

Most posts I've found, suggests this issue shouldn't be possible ><
Output from winget pin list


What operating system do you use? When did you first install chrome?

Tagged as Windows 11 :)
I have no idea when Chrome was first installed, but I suspect it's the locked version.

Have you tried the winget pin command as suggested to find out what is preventing the upgrade? Otherwise have you tried simply downloading the installer from https://www.google.com/intl/en_uk/chrome/ ?

[Edit] your question to include the output of the winget pin --include-pinned command.

Do you mean winget pin list ? @Ramhound

As a ditch effort, I tried the suggestion from @Mokubai. That worked.
I do not see the old version mentioned anywhere in the registry, so using an installer from google directly seemed to have done the trick.

@HaraldS.Hanssen - No, I mean the command that was suggested in your screenshot. Chrome uses Visual C++, you have an out of date version installed, although i suspect Google does not keep the winget version of Chrome updated.  Chrome 70 is multiple years old

i suspect Google does not keep the winget version of Chrome updated I've had winget suggest a newer version even when Chrome itself thinks it is up to date

@ramhound that makes sense

Checked versions on both msi’s (x86 and x64) which are linked to the winget package. Both are version 124.*
I suspect that something else is going on.

Are you sure the binary is actually the old version? I remember something about there is a version on the MSI installer that is different than chrome.exe version and in rare instances the registry version gets recorded as the installer version instead of the installed application version. I think this was acknowledged in Google's bug tracker but its been ages and I can't find the link.  I'm looking at an inventory report for our environment of 5000+ devices and show 11 on 70.55.49213, but if I UNC over to their folders, it is v124.  In fact, this inventory report is from 4 days ago, and as of today, the DisplayVersion in the registry is correct on the 1st 2 I looked at. This is certainly annoying because these systems get flagged as having a vulnerable version when in fact they do not.
EDIT: Found the link https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-bugs/c/cVVuOiWsAbY/m/cC2yoa_88jcJ?pli=1

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
